# Symfony array of objects deserialization

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I have this class:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Uid\Ulid;

final class Payload
{
    /**
     * @param Ulid[] $ulidList
     */
    public function __construct(
        public readonly string $id,
        public readonly array $ulidList,
    ) {
    }
}
```

when serializing it

```php
$this->serializer->serialize($payload, 'json');
```

I'm receiving this output:

```json
{"id":"XXX","ulidList":["01GP9H0WPW2A2BK9GYV9GQJMAK"]}
```

but when de-serializing the above

```php
$this->serializer->deserialize($data, Payload::class, 'json');
```

the `$ulidList` property is filled with array of strings instead of `Ulid` objects.

How to make it to fill it with `Ulid`? I'm using `SerializerInterface` loaded from Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making my own instance of `Serializer` with this way:

```php
$this->serializer = new Serializer(
    normalizers: [
        new UidNormalizer(),
        new ArrayDenormalizer(),
        new ObjectNormalizer(
            propertyTypeExtractor: new PropertyInfoExtractor(
                typeExtractors: [new PhpDocExtractor(), new ReflectionExtractor()],
            ),
        ),
    ],
    encoders: [
        new JsonEncoder(),
    ],
);
```

What I was missing is the `ObjectNormalizer` with properly filled `propertyTypeExtractor` and `ArrayDenormalizer`.